# parse URL params in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on some tutorials to explain things like GET/POST's and need to parse the URI manually.  The follow perl code works, but I am trying to do two things:

1. list each key/value
2. be able to look up one specific value

What I do NOT care about is replacing the special chars to spaces or anything, the one value I need to get should be a number.  In other languages I have used, the regular expression in question should group each key/value into one grouping with a part 1/part 2, does Perl do the same?  If so, how do I put that into a map?

```
my @paramList = split /(?:\?|&|;)([^=]+)=([^&|;]+)/, $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'};
if(@paramList)
{
    print "<h1>The Params</h1><ul>";
    foreach my $i (@paramList) {
        if($i) {
        print "<li>$i</li>"; 
        }
    }
    print "<ul>";
}
```

Per the request, here is a basic example of the input:

`REQUEST_URI = /cgi-bin/printenv_html.pl?customer_name=fdas&phone_number=fdsa&email_address=fads%40fd.com&taxi=van&extras=tip&pickup_time=2020-01-14T20%3A45&pickup_place=&dropoff_place=Airport&comments=`

goal is the following where the left of the equal is the key, and the right is the value:

```
customer_name=fdas
phone_number=fdsa
email_address=fads%40fd.com
taxi=van
extras=tip
pickup_time=2020-01-14T20%3A45
pickup_place=
dropoff_place=Airport
comments=
```

Comment: It'd be nice to see a sample of that `ENV` variable (and s0 why/how `split` is needed) ?

Comment: can do, I have added that to the post.

Comment: Thank you, got it -- edited my answer ... still checking ... is that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about feeding your list of key-value pairs into a hash?

```
my %paramList = $ENV{'REQUEST_URI'} =~ /(?:\?|&|;)([^=]+)=([^&|;]+)/g;
```

(no reason for the `split` as far as I can tell)

This relies crucially on there being an even-sized list of matches, where each "before-`=`" thing becomes a key in the hash, with the value being its pairing "after-`=`" thing.

In order to also get "pairs" without a value (like `comments=`) change `+` in the last pattern to `*`

Comment: The only tweak was to my regex, needed to change the final + to * to also capture the ones that do NOT have values, all is good, thank you!

Comment: @SamCarleton Right! Just noticed that, tested, and updated with a comment